# Prove a simple inequality

Tags: inequality

$$ y\in R$$
Prove: 
if for every positive number $b$:
$$ \left\lvert y \right\rvert  \leq b $$
so $y=0$

I tried seperating into cases where

$$ -b\leq y\leq 0 $$ and $$ 0\leq y\leq b $$

But I can't see where it helps me, any ideas? thanks

Comment: Suppose $y\neq0$.  Surely, $y/2\neq0$. What can you conclude for $b=|y/2|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $y\neq 0$, then, there exist a $c>0$ such that 
$$|y|\geq c>0$$
which is a contradiction with
$$\forall b> 0, |y|\leq b,$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Assume on the contrary $y \neq 0$.

Then $\frac{|y|}{2} > 0$ and hence $\frac{|y|}{2} \geq |y|$ and thus $|y| \leq 0$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

By the hypothesis we have

$$\forall b>0,\quad |y|\le b$$
which means that $|y|$ is a lower bound for the set $\Bbb R_{>0}$ so $|y|\le 0 $ : the greatest lower bound of this set hence we get $$0\le |y|\le 0\implies |y|=0\implies y=0$$